# How do I represent the minimum contribution percentage while allowing users to change the figures on the page and still default to the 50% OnPageLoad

Tags: sliders, numbers, controlled-vocabulary

Action:
moving the slider adjusts the pricing on the page for an insurance package.

Scenario:
A user select a insurance benefit package for their employees. The minimum they can contribute is 50% of the total premium cost. The employer pays half and the employee pays half. By increasing the the contribution amount the employer is contributing more toward the employees monthly cost.

Problem: The slider controller is set at the minimum 50% (left) where users are conditioned to think this placement mean 0 (zero). If I place the slider in the middle the user will think they can contribute less then 50%. [image]

Answer (score 2):

How about this? grey out the part of the slider you can't use.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpHtg8.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Midas having the controller start in the middle is confusing as to why your starting at 50% and can't drop below it.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what the scenario you've described is?